# Linear systems of ODEs with block structure

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Consider the following problem. Imagine having a set of ordinary linear differential equations (the system is homogeneous):

$$\dot{\mathbf{C}}(t) = \mathbf{M} \cdot \mathbf{C}(t)$$,
where:
$$\mathbf{M} = \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{m^{(1,1)}} & \mathbf{m^{(1,2)}} & ... & \mathbf{m^{(1,N_2)}} \\
\mathbf{m^{(2,1)}} & \mathbf{m^{(2,2)}} & ... & \mathbf{m^{(2,N_2)}} \\
... & ... & ... & ... \\
\mathbf{m^{(N_1,1)}} & \mathbf{m^{(N_1,2)}} & ... & \mathbf{m^{(N_1,N_2)}}
\end{pmatrix}; \quad \mathbf{C}(t) = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{c^{(1)}}(t) \\
\mathbf{c^{(2)}}(t) \\
... \\
\mathbf{c^{(N_2)}}(t)
\end{pmatrix}$$.

Entries for both tensors $\mathbf{M}, \mathbf{C}(t)$ can be complex, in general. So, basically, it is just a system of ODEs with block structure. Each block $\mathbf{c^{(j)}}(t)$ has a particular physical meaning (which does not really matter for this question), and blocks $\mathbf{m^{(i,j)}}$ account for the interactions between the blocks $\mathbf{c^{i}}(t)$, and $\mathbf{c^{j}}(t)$. Let us also consider that $\mathbf{C}^\dagger(t) \cdot \mathbf{C}(t) = 1$, so it is normalized.

Imagine that I start with some initial condition such that only a single block with label $j_0$ contains non-zero elements: $c^{(j=j_0)}_k(t=0) \ne 0$, while $c^{(j\ne j_0)}_k(t=0) = 0$ for any $k$.

My question is: how one can estimate the values of $c^{(j\ne j_0)}_k(t) = 0$ from both the matrix of coefficients $\mathbf{M}$, and the initial condition vector, which is a single non-zero block $c^{(j = j_0)}_k(t=0)$?

A special interest is in the stationary state, which is the  nullspace of $\mathbf{M}$? (It is guaranteed that the nullspace has exactly $1$ vector, which comes from some physical condition of the problem, so it is a unique stationary state).

Thank you in advance, this question puzzles me a lot!

P.S.: I will add a small comment on the motivation. Basically, the initial problem is extremely hard to solve: the matrix $\mathbf{M}$ is way too big to solve on a regular PC. So, I want to understand, whether I can discard some specific blocks completely, and simplify the problem significantly.

**UPDATE of 09.11.2020**

I think that the problem "as is" might sound too general, and that there might not be a simple, and meaningful answer, apart from "just compute numerically". So, I suggest the following modification of the problem, that, I hope, will make more sense to the audience.

Suppose we start from the following homogenous system:
$$
\mathbf{\dot{c}^{(1)}}(t) = \mathbf{m^{(1,1)}} \cdot  \mathbf{c^{(1)}}(t),
$$
where $\mathbf{m^{(1,1)}}$ is a square matrix of size $n_1$, and $\mathbf{c^{(1)}}(t)$ is, correspondingly, a column vector with $n_1$ components. Imagine that we know everything about the system: the eigendecomposition $\mathbf{S}(\mathbf{m^{(1,1)}})$ (matrix of eigenvectors), $\Lambda(\mathbf{m^{(1,1)}})$ (matrix of eigenvalues), the stationary state $\mathbf{c^{(1,\infty)}}$ (a single stationary state, the nullspace of $\mathbf{m^{(1,1)}})$ or we can find everything that might help us in the future. All that implies that it is possible to find all these quantities, so the matrix $\mathbf{m^{(1,1)}}$ is diagonalizable, and has a rank of $n_1 - 1$ (so that the nullspace is exactly of dimension 1 - we have a unique stationary state).

Now imagine that we add some more degrees of freedom into the system, so it looks like this:

$$ \dfrac{d}{dt} \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{c^{(1)}}(t) \\ \mathbf{c^{(2)}}(t) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
\mathbf{m^{(1,1)}} & \mathbf{m^{(1,2)}} \\
\mathbf{m^{(2,1)}} & \mathbf{m^{(2,2)}}
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{c^{(1)}}(t) \\ \mathbf{c^{(2)}}(t) \end{pmatrix},$$
where $\mathbf{c^{(2)}}(t)$ is a column vector with $n_2$ components, and blocks $\mathbf{m^{(1,2)}}, \mathbf{m^{(2,1)}}, \mathbf{m^{(2,2)}}$ have corresponding dimensions.

The question is, basically, the same: does the knowledge on $\mathbf{m^{(1,1)}}$ help us to find **a new stationary state of this bigger system**? Such an approach makes the solution of the original problem somewhat recursive, so if for $2 \times 2$ block matrix it can be done, then it can be done for a general case.